Jetbrains Rider: touching Macbook's built-in keyboard or touchpad changes input mode to overwrite
I am using two versions of Rider (2023.3.5 and 2024.1.2) on my new Macbook (2021, 16-inch). Both have the same issue since I installed them, that any type of input done with its built-in keyboard or touchpad changes the typing mode to overwrite, as if the insert key was pressed.
I tried pressing different key shortcuts that are the natural equivalent of Macbook's INSERT key without any luck, I also tried binding a shortcut in Rider's Keymaps under Toggle Insert/Overwrite to switch the typing mode this way, also no luck. The only way to type normally in my files is to use external keyboard (in which case, typing any signs automatically switches the typing mode to insert without even the need of pressing any shortcuts).
I find it very frustrating, and it disables any chances of working with Rider for me outside of home, since I can't rely on carrying an extra set of keyboard and mouse everywhere I go. Is there any fix to this issue available?

Do you have IdeaVim or any other plugin installed that could change the input mode?
Please check if the issue persists after disabling all downloaded plugins.
